# Htaccess Rewrite First Paramater To Virtual Directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite only the parameter `type` of an url to a virtual directory.

THIS

```
example.com/v1/example/?a=b&c=d&e=f …
```

SHOULD LOAD

```
example.com/v1/index.php?type=example&a=b&c=d&e=f …
```

One of my tries:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v1/example/?(.*) v1/index.php?type=example$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is "`example`" variable? If so, how variable? What are the criteria?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^v1/example/?(.*) v1/index.php?type=example$1 [L,QSA,NC]
> ```

This should actually have "worked" (by chance) for this particular example, but it is based on some misconceptions.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only. To match the query string you would need a separate *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable. However, it doesn't seem like you need to match against the query string at all, you just need to add to it.

For example, to rewrite the example request, you could use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v1/example/$ v1/index.php?type=example [QSA,L]
```

The `QSA` flag appends the original query string (if any) onto the rewritten request.

I would question the use of the `NC` flag here (which is why I've removed it) since it potentially promotes duplicate content.

Also note that the order of the directives in the `.htaccess` can be important, so you may not be able to put this rule "anywhere". You need to avoid conflicts with other rules.

If, however, `example` (the 2nd path segment) is *variable* then you could do something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^v1/([\w-]+)/$ v1/index.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Where `example` can consist only of the characters `0-9`, `a-z`, `A-Z`, `_` (underscore) and `-` (hyphen) as denoted by the regex `[\w-]+`. And must be 1 or more of such characters.

Also consider extracting the first path segment, to avoid repetition. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(v1)/([\w-]+)/$ $1/index.php?type=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer! I had no time to test it yet, but it sounds like this is what I need! Is is possible to write private messages here? Could you send me your PayPal-e-mail, so that I can return the favor for the time invested?